# ¿Cómo puedo obtener campos no traducidos en Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando seleccionar los campos que no están traducidos, pero no puedo encontrar una manera de hacerlo.

**Languages Table**

```
+---------------+---------------+
| language_name | language_code |
+---------------+---------------+
| English       | en            |
| Español       | es            |
| Italiano      | it            |
+---------------+---------------+
```

**Status Table**

```
+-----------+
| status_id |
+-----------+
| 1         |
| 2         |
+-----------+
```

**Translation Status Table**

```
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+----+
| tr_status_id | tr_status_translate | tr_lang |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+----+
| 1            | for rent            | en      |
| 2            | for sale            | en      |
| 1            | alquiler            | es      |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+----+
```

**Mysql Query**

```
SELECT languages.*, tr_ptstatus.* 
FROM languages, tr_ptstatus 
WHERE languages.language_code NOT IN (
    SELECT tr_lang FROM tr_ptstatus
) 
GROUP BY language_code
```

Por ejemplo, en la tabla de **tr_ptstatus** aún no está por traducir **for sale** al español y al italiano.

El resultado que quiero obtener en pantalla es:

**for sale** is not translated to **Español**
**for sale** is not translated to **Italiano**
**for rent** is not translated to **Italiano**

Comment: Y no sirve contar los status_id que sean menores que 2?? esos seguro estan en un solo idioma

Comment: Igual tu consulta falla porque esta haciendo un producto cartesiano porque no tiene ninguna clausula de join

Comment: y como lo puedo resolver? es la primera vez que un proyecto asi y mi nivel con mysql es basico. gracias.

Comment: Sabes algo sobre joins o group by? o el codigo que tiraste fue porque si? Es importante esto, porque podemos hacer tu query, pero sin esos conocimientos va a ser lo mismo que nada. Si no, te recomendaria ya que empezaras con un manual de sql

Comment: si ya he trabajado con joins y group by de hecho ya he probado con joins y group by pero sin resultado, seguramente estoy haciendo mal, por necesito ayuda para saber cual es el problema o que lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Ok.. entonces intenta con lo que te dije, cuenta los status_id menores que dos en la tabla translation status y esos serian los que no estan traducidos. Y ten en cuenta que la consulta que pusiste como ejemplo, falla porque esta mal el join y el group by. Esa consulta solo anda en mysql, en cualquier otra base de datos tiraria error.

Comment: Una vez que intentes eso, muestranos como progresaste y asi corregirte lo que estas haciendo mal...

Comment: no entiendo exactamente a lo que te refieres con (cuenta los status_id menores)

Comment: que hagas el count del campo status_id, y te quedes con aquellos cuya cuenta sea menor que dos (que se supone, no estan traducidos porque aparacen una sola vez en la tabla ;) )

Comment: Ah vale, pero creo que eso no me va a servir porque si añado un tercer idioma tendría que volver a modificar el query para hacer el count

Comment: si hay mas de 2 idiomas el query es totalmente diferente, y no es lo que planteaste en tu pregunta.. por eso es importante plantear las preguntas reales y no lo que uno cree que podria solucionar el problema. Tenes mas de un idioma? queres saber registro X registro que idiomas faltan? entonces tu query tampoco funcionaria ni de casualidad. Por favor, usa el boton [edit], modifica tu pregunta y ponela lo mas realista posible, con la salida esperada (en sql, esa no es una salida esperada) y borremos todos los comentarios. Deja bien clara la pregunta

Comment: Ya lo he modificado

Comment: [Estes es uno de los mejores modelos que he visto para traducciones múltiples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10734542/5587982), te lo dejo por si te puede servir.

Answer (score 1):

Obtengamos la cantidad de idiomas:

```
select count(*) from Languages
```

Y ahora, contemos los registros en translation_status cuya cuenta de menos que eso:

```
select tr_status_id , count(*) 
from translation_status 
group by tr_status_id 
having count(*) < (select count(*) from languages)
```

Esto nos va a devolver una lista de tr_status_id que no estan traducidos a todos los idiomas.. ahora para saber que idiomas no estan, es complicado, porque tenemos que inventar registros, ya que sabemos en cuales estan, pero no en cuales no estan.

Asi que lo que vamos a hacer es una lista de todos los idiomas y le unimos por derecha la query anterior, y nos quedamos solo con los registros que tengan tr_status_translate  vacio...

```
select language_code, tr_status_id, tr_status_translate 
from Languages left join translation_status as status ON tr_lang = language_code
where
    tr_status_id in (select tr_status_id 
                    from translation_status 
                    group by tr_status_id 
                    having count(*) < (select count(*) from languages)
    and
        length(tr_status_translate) = 0
```

NOTA: esto esta sacado a mano y no esta probado.

Comment: ok déjame leerlo y entender bien lo que has hecho y luego lo probare si funciona asi aprendo.

Comment: lo he probado pero no me funciona.

Comment: y con tan poca informacion poco puedo hacer.. que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: no se que informacion necesitas es todo lo que hay, en todo caso, me puedes explicar lo que hace esta linea exactamente (from Languages left join translation_status as status) el AS status lo asignas pero no lo usas o estoy equivocado ?

Comment: exacto.. no lo uso.. igual que error tira, o que hace que no funcione?

Comment: por ejemplo he probado esta query y no imprime ningún resultado (select tr_status_id , count(*) from translation_status group by tr_status_id having count(*) < (select count(*) from languages))

Comment: te recomendaria que generes un fiddle en algun lado, cargues los datos y asi podamos trabajarlo mejor

Comment: Ye he creado uno aqui tienes el enlace: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0f9f9/1

Comment: No tiene solucion esto verdad?

Comment: Si que la debe tener.. te recomendaria que el fiddle este en la pregunta y los campos y los querys respeten lo que dice la pregunta.

Comment: es por simplificar la pregunta nada mas, pero en cuanto lo resuelva voy a actualizar la pregunta.

Comment: he probado tu query pero el resultado es lo que ya estan traducidas no lo contrario, esto quitando esta parte (and
        length(tr_status_translate) = 0) y cerrando parentesis al final.